# Show that the equation of motion for a particle on Norton's Dome is $\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=r^{1/2}$

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation, classical-mechanics

> A particle sits at the top of a dome, whose height drops away from the centre, with a drop given by $$h=\frac{2r^{3/2}}{3g}$$ where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and $r$ is a coordinate measured radially along
>   the surface from the peak. At $t = 0$ the particle is at rest at the top of the dome.
>
> Show that the equation of motion is
>   $$\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=r^{1/2}\tag{1}$$

[image: Dome]

Resolving the gravitational acceleration along the surface, $g \cos\theta$,
where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface and the vertical. A sketch shows that $dh = \cos \theta \,dr$. Hence $$\cos \theta = \frac{dh}{dr}=\frac{r^{1/2}}{g}$$

I am unable to proceed any further. Could someone please explain to me how to obtain equation $(1)$?

---

**Note:** Please do not migrate this to Physics.SE (it's already there). What I am asking here is purely about the mathematics behind equation $(1)$. Thanks.

Comment: Try to compute the component of the gravitational force along the path $g_{||}$. Given this component then we have $r'' = g_{||}$ by Newton's second law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider conservation of energy, which gives $$\frac 12 m\dot{r}^2=mgh$$

Now differentiate this with respect to time so you have $$m\dot{r}\ddot{r}=mg\frac{dh}{dt}$$

You also have $$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{r^{\frac 12}\dot{r}}{g}$$ and the result follows immediately

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like your energy conservation approach. If $\dot{r}=\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ then $\dfrac{dh}{dt}=\dfrac{r^{\frac 12 }}{g}\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ how does the result follow from this?

Comment: The $\dot{r}$ term cancels on both sides

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Differentiating the energy equation with respect to time is a very useful method for obtaining the equation of motion in many situations

Answer (score 3):

Here is a physics proof:
$$\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$$ is the acceleration over path $r$. Denote as a.

[image]

It is easy to show that $a = g sin(\gamma) = g cos(\theta) = g \frac{r^{1/2}}{g} = r^{1/2}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: You are welcome.