# When do differential operators commute?

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation, classical-mechanics

> Given that the equation of motion of a particle placed on the apex of Norton's Dome is [$$\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=r^{1/2}\qquad\longleftarrow\text{as proved in this previous question}\tag{1}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855586/show-that-the-equation-of-motion-for-a-particle-on-nortons-dome-is-fracd2-r) Solve this non-linear equation by multiplying both sides by $$2\frac{dr}{dt}$$ and integrating to find that $$r(t)=\frac{\left(t-T\right)^4}{144}$$ for any $T\ge 0$.

[image: Dome]

---

Pre-multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $$2\frac{dr}{dt}$$ gives $$2\color{red}{\frac{dr}{dt}}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}\right)}=2\frac{dr}{dt}r^{1/2}\tag{2}$$

Rewriting $(2)$ $\bbox[yellow]{\text{with the order of the red and blue factors switched}}$ gives:

$$2\color{blue}{\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}}\color{red}{\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)}=2\frac{dr}{dt}r^{1/2}\tag{3}$$ The reason for the switch is because the blue factor in $(3)$ is the derivative of the red factor (I had to write it this way in order to integrate by inspection). Integrating both sides gives $$\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{4}{3}r^{3/2}+C\tag{4}$$

In obtaining $(4)$ from $(3)$ I used the chain rule on the RHS, namely $$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}$$

Finally, my question is all about the validity of the sentence highlighted in yellow. I am aware that differential operators do not commute in general. So is it plausible for me to simply switch the order of the red and blue factors as I did in getting from $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Many thanks.

Comment: The red and blue items aren't operators; they're just functions.

Comment: @anomaly Thanks for your reply; So the switch of order is completely justified?

Comment: You can prove that the first and second derivative operators commute?

Comment: @anomaly If $\dfrac{dr}{dr}$ and $\dfrac{d^2r}{dt^2}$ are not differential operators then is $\dfrac{d}{dr}$ a differential operator?

Comment: Okay now explain the downvote

Comment: Sure. (........)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About Switching Operators**

I hope that I am not missing something! :)

I think what you are asking is the same as that the multiplication of two real numbers is commutative or not!

The answer is **YES**, as you know that one can write

$$a\cdot b=b\cdot a$$

where $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers.

In fact, in your problem no operator switching is involved

$$\color{red}{\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)} \color{blue}{\left(\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}\right)}=ab=ba=\color{blue}{\left(\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}\right)}\color{red}{\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)}$$

---

**Another Way to Solve**

There is another way for solving $(1)$ that you do not need to multiply by $2\frac{dr}{dt}$!

I will give you a hint. Consider the following

$$\ddot r  = {{{d^2}r } \over {d{t^2}}} = {d \over {dt}}\left( {{{dr } \over {dt}}} \right) = {d \over {dr }}\left( {{{dr } \over {dt}}} \right){{dr } \over {dt}} = \dot r {d \over {dr }}\left( {\dot r } \right) = {d \over {dr }}\left( {{1 \over 2}{{\dot r }^2}} \right)$$

and hence your ode in $(1)$ becomes

$${d \over {dr }}\left( {{1 \over 2}{{\dot r }^2}} \right)=r^{1/2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the red and blue factors are not differential operators, then what is an example of a differential operator?

Comment: @BLAZE those are the functions After being applied by a differential operator

Comment: $ \frac{d}{dt} $ and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ are the operators themselves. Note that $$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d^2}{dt^2}[r] $$ is a very different from $$ \frac{dr}{dt} \frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas So a differential operator is $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ for example?

Comment: Correct, and these too have a certain "commutative" property, but it is different than what your question deals with.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Thanks, do you agree that I must switch the order of the red and blue terms in order to carry out the integration?

Comment: no, the integration can be carried in either order, by switching, the author hopes to remind you of the familiar $\frac{d}{dx}(m(x))^2 = 2 m'(x) m(x)$, but this is just as true as $= m(x)*2*m'(x)$ or any other permutation for that matter. Once you have a "feel" for what's going on, you don't need to do specific re-orderings the way the author does

Comment: @H.R. Reading it now thanks :)

Comment: @H.R Actually, it wasn't even _my_ reasoning; it was the reasoning of the answer of the author to the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the question of commutation of two ordinary differential operators (ODO) is not a trivial one. If two ODOs commute, then they necessarily satisfy a polynomial relationship (by work of Burchnall and Chaundy). In particular, their eigenvalues lie on an affine algebraic curve (its projective completion is called spectral curve). The mutual eigenfunctions (so-called Baker-Akhiezer functions) of commuting ODOs form a vector bundle over the spectral curve.

When BA bundle's rank $r=1$, Krichever has given an explicit expression for the coefficients of operators in terms of the $\theta$-function of the Jacobian of the spectral curve.

In the case $r>1$, the problem gets more difficult and, to the best of my knowledge, is far from being completely solved. Krichever and Novikov found an explicit expression for operators with elliptic spectral curve ($g=1$) with $r=2$. Mokhov has treated the case $g=1, \: r=3$. Mironov has given examples of commuting differential operators of $r=2$ with hyperelliptic spectral curve of arbitrary genus. Zuo's given an example of operators with $g=2, \: r=3$.